# how to get the results of a for loop in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe

I have made a sentiment analyses on a couple of tweets from Twitter. I made this in a for loop and got the results I needed. The next step is to put it into a DataFrame.
I am trying to put a for loop into a DataFrame.
This is the for loop:

```
x = 1

for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(x)
    print(tweet.text)
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
    x= x+1
```

I want to have two columns called 'Tweets' and 'Sentiment'. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

```
import pandas as pd

x = 1
d = {}      #Create a dict with tweet and sentiment
for tweet in public_tweets:
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
    x= x+1
    d[tweet.text] = analysis.sentiment

c = ['Tweets','Sentiment']    
df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=c)   #form a DF.
```

Comment: I tried it out. Alas I got this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'Status'

Comment: It shows that error on the line 'd[tweet] = analysis.sentiment'

Comment: On the last line, I got the error : ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: Sir, you are amazing. This worked! Thank you very much!